# I have character on keyboard, but I can't input it

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, keyboard-layout

I can't enter character `|`, but I have this character on keyboard. I need this for Java (`if x == 2 || x == 3`)

And second, not important question, but also <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> give me `"`, not `@`. This keys swiped.

I am on Lubuntu.

Please, give simple solution.

Comment: It sounds to me that you need to go to your System Settings and check that the keyboard is set to the correct country.

Comment: This is on US or GB or RU keyboard layout. Default keyboard model set to pc105 - and from this long list I don't know my keyboard - I have laptop Sony Vaio VGN-C140G.

Comment: Use the key in the left side of the number one to get |, you will get @ by hitting AltGr+2 or AltGr+Q in certain cases. Please confirm if this helps in order to add it as an answer. BTW: AltGr = Right Alt. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! I can get | by pushing AltGr + "key-left-before-1", but is it possible to sync physical labels on keyboard with keyboard layout in Lubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your **Layout Chart**  by following below images. For english it should be like this:

[image: Layout Chart]

So, to use `|` character, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>.

If you use another input language, this **Layout Chart** it will look different. So you need to check how.

Comment: My Dear, I am on Lubuntu.

Comment: And what is the problem? You can't find Layout Chart?

Comment: Yes, Lubuntu not have Layout Chart.

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich Sure... What you say about this: To add a layout indicator to the panel - right click on the panel - Add / remove panel items - Panel Applets  - Add - Keyboard Layout Switcher.

Comment: Lubuntu _does_ have a layout chart: open Universal Access->On Board

Comment: I can add to panel only Keyboard Layout Handler, not Keyboard Layout Switcher (Lubuntu 13.04).

Comment: Thank you very much, my dear AskUbuntu! I fix this problem with changing my english keyboard layout from Great Britain to USA and `@`, `"` and `|` now syncing with images on my physical keyboard. And, yes, I install `onboard` from Synaptic (removed in past) and review my keyboard layout. Thank you all for help!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have the wrong keyboard set.  The keyboard layout varies in different countries and I have the <kbd>"</kbd> on <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>; this is the default in the UK.

You were asked what keyboard layout you wanted when you installed but I think it defaults to a UK keyboard. Luckily you don't need to reinstall to change it.

From the Menu select "Preferences" > "Keyboard and mouse"

In the application that opens select the "Keyboard" tab and click lxkeymap as shown

[image: img]

This opens a new window

[image: img2]

From here you can select the keyboard layout that matches your computer and select Apply.

Job done, the new setting will be remembered.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the keycode for the | key to another one. (7c is | according to xev)... Hope that helps you out.